# Android Fragment, ListView NullPointer Exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, cursor, fragment, simplecursoradapter

I am creating a ListView in my Fragment Class that shall simple list contacts from the app database.  I do not have anything fancy as of yet since I am just now creating it.  For the moment I am getting a NullPointer error the looks like it is pointing to the onCreate, but I can not see the error.  perhaps you guys will.

```
public class ContactsFragment extends ListFragment {

    Context fContext;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter contactCursorAdapter;

    public ContactsFragment(){}
    private View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fContext = getActivity();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);

        //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
        contactListView();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void contactListView() {

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(fContext);
        Cursor contactCursor = db.fetchContacts();

        // Allow activity to manage the lifetime of the cursor
        //startManagingCursor(contactCursor);

        //Setup mapping of cursor
        String[] fromFields = new String[]
                {db.KEY_NAMECONCAT,
                db.KEY_COMPANY};
        int[] toViewIds = new int[]
                {R.id.tvFullName,
                R.id.tvContactCompany};

        //Create Adapter
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SimpleCursorAdapter contactCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                fContext,
                R.layout.contact_list_item,
                contactCursor,
                fromFields,
                toViewIds
                );

        //Set the adapter for the List View
        ListView contactList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listContacts);
        contactList.setAdapter(contactCursorAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        db.close();
    }

}
```

fragment_contacts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listContacts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</ListView>
```

contact_list_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFullName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="FullName"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContactCompany"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvFullName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvFullName"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Company" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.garudaapps.myapp, PID: 30894
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.garudaapps.myapp.ContactsFragment.contactListView(ContactsFragment.java:89)
    at com.garudaapps.myapp.ContactsFragment.onCreateView(ContactsFragment.java:35)
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It could be that the context is wrong or it could be what it normally is and there is an element in the code which does not really exist.  Either way, I simply do not see it

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**You have initialize list reference in wrong place.**

```
public class ContactsFragment extends ListFragment {

    Context fContext;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

    public ContactsFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fContext = getActivity();
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);

        //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
        ListView contactList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listContacts);
        contactListView();
        contactList.setAdapter(contactCursorAdapter);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void contactListView() {

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(fContext);
        Cursor contactCursor = db.fetchContacts();

        // Allow activity to manage the lifetime of the cursor
        //startManagingCursor(contactCursor);

        //Setup mapping of cursor
        String[] fromFields = new String[]
                {db.KEY_NAMECONCAT,
                        db.KEY_COMPANY};
        int[] toViewIds = new int[]
                {R.id.tvFullName,
                        R.id.tvContactCompany};

        //Create Adapter
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        SimpleCursorAdapter contactCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                fContext,
                R.layout.contact_list_item,
                contactCursor,
                fromFields,
                toViewIds
        );

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        db.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: only problem with this one is the contactList.setAdapter anfter the ListView initialization.

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the contactListView() method

Comment: one more hint, it also looks like the problem is at ListView contactList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listContacts);  where it appears to not find the listContacts which is the list view.  Could it be that since this is a fragment that the getActivity() is not ocrrect?